# differences in unit testing frameworks and how to use

Tags: windows, unit-testing

I am trying to compare the following test frameworks

•   Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++
•   Google Test
•   Boost.Test
•   CTest

And I am lost.  Which is best?  And how to write test-driven development.  We are a Microsoft shop with 80% C++ code and 20% c#

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a link](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/c-unit-testing-framework) that might help you decide.